# Javascript declaring a variable with complex JSON format

Tags: javascript, variables, jsonschema

I am pretty new to javascript.
I am trying to declare a variable that contains strings and nested arrays.
ex:- 
i need a variable that holds,
array (tableName,fields and multiple comments for each field).

Here is my code,

```
var data = [ {tableName : String, [{fieldName : String, [comments:String]}] } ]
```

This is not working, please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays, denoted [ value1, value2 ], can only have values in them.

Objects, denoted { key1: value1, key2: value2 }, only have key-value pairs.

It's easier to see the problem if you write it out on multiple lines:

```
var data = [
   { //we're in an object
      tableName: "some-string",
      //this next value doesn't have an associated key
      [
         {  //we're in an object
             fieldName: "some-other-string",
             //this next value doesn't have an associated key
             [ 
                 comments: "some-comments-string" //we're in an array, so key-value pairs don't work.
             ]
         }
      ]
   }
];
```

I strongly recommend some sort of static analyzer like eslint to help spot these types of problems. You probably meant to do something like this (but the question doesn't make it clear):

```
var data = [
   { 
      tableName: "some-table-name",
      fields: [
         {  
             fieldName: "some-field-name",                 
             comments: [ 
                 "some-comment-1",
                 "some-comment-2"
             ]
         }
      ]
   }
];
```

If you're confused about the difference between Arrays and Objects in javascript, try here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. but I don't want to populate my data while declaring. I just want to declare with data types and will populate dynamically later. Let me know the possibility.

Comment: My ultimate goal here is, I am getting a response in json format as mentioned and i want store it to mongoDb

Comment: Javascript doesn't really do this sort of thing - it's not a statically typed language so you don't define your data structures in advance (you can, but it's not really the way things are generally done). It uses "duck" typing - in other words, if your object has the necessary fields for a particular purpose, then it has the correct type for that purpose.

Comment: So you don't need to know in advance the structure that you're receiving in JSON - you can just do "var data = JSON.stringify( incomingJSON );". If you want to validate that data after that, you can - but it's not really part of javascript.

Comment: Hope this gives you enough of an idea to make some progress. If not, show a bit more of your actual code and I can probably give you a bit more direction.